# How to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis on WildFly with Hawt.io

Tags: wildfly, hawtio, activemq-artemis

I have ActiveMQ Artemis embedded to WildFly10 (as it comes) and want to monitor it via Hawt.io.

What I did:

- ActiveMQ Artemis is configured and running
- I dropped hawtio.war to deployment directory.
- I dropped builded by maven artemis-plugin with name chanaged just to artemis-plugin.war
- I even dropped jolokia.war

I tried with the standalone jar - made a plugin directory and put artemis-plugin.war there.

when I connect to jolokia I get CPU usage (and stuff like that) for WildFly, I can see, via JMX the queue, but still, to success with Artemis.

hawtio doesnot recognize the pluginhawtio doesnot recognize the plugin however it got loaded:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - An Artemis plugin at http://0.0.0.0:8081/artemis-plugin
[main] INFO jetty - Added 3rd party plugin with context-path: /artemis-plugin
Added 3rd party plugin with context-path: /artemis-plugin
```

I donot have 'Artemis' tab. , going to http://0.0.0.0:8081/artemis-plugin shows me the dir:

Directory: /artemis-plugin/

```
META-INF/   4096 bytes  Aug 4, 2016 10:41:10 AM
WEB-INF/    4096 bytes  Aug 4, 2016 10:41:10 AM
log4j.properties    215 bytes   Aug 3, 2016 3:39:10 PM
plugin/     4096 bytes  Aug 4, 2016 10:41:09 AM
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jmx managment has to be switched on:

`<management jmx-enabled="true"/>`

[source](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/271770)